# Count number of resullts on table B from values in table A using single query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to count the number of results matched in table B from values drawn from table A in the same query?

For example -

```
tableA
--------------
color  | type
-------|------
blue   | car
red    | truck
orange | car
green  | car
```

-

```
tableB
--------------
color  | sku
-------|------
blue   | 1
red    | 2
orange | 3
green  | 4
orange | 5
green  | 6
```

Question -  How many rows in tableB are related to type = car?  Result should return 5.

Using two queries and some PHP this is pretty straightforward, I was just curious if this is possible with a single MySQL query, and if it would be more efficient.

Comment: try this : SELECT count(*) FROM tableB as tb LEFT JOIN tableB as ta ON ta.color = tb.color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below query

```
SELECT count(*) AS count 
FROM tableB b, tableA a 
WHERE b.color = a.color 
AND type = 'car';
```

Answer (score 2):

Join your tables on the colors that correspond to your type :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB JOIN tableA using (color) WHERE type = 'car';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/760da5/1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I accepted user304 because it allowed for more customization as far as columns being titled something different across the two tables and because he has less rep.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.color=tableB.color
AND tableA.type='car';
```